# iframe causes parent elements to scroll up on Google Chrome when URL contains fragment

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, jsfiddle

On Google Chrome (37.0.2062.122, OSX / Windows), an iframe with an URL containing a fragment causes the parent elements to scroll up.

It's only happening in Chrome (tested in Safari and Firefox).

Here's a Fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/wmz5cu1y/1/ (you have to click `Run` *twice*.)

As you can see, the whole `<body>` containing the iframe has scrolled up. The header is hidden because it's now above the window, and there is an unexpected blank space at the bottom of the page.

How to avoid this ?

Bounty offered for a non-js workaround or a simpler html document reproducing the issue.

[image: iframe overflows body]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the problem? For me both Chrome and Firefox both scroll the iframe to the content whose ID is #up_8360397.

Comment: Sorry, just added one.

Comment: So the problem is, on load it starts halfway down the page?

Comment: Not really, when the iframe loads and scroll to the fragment, the body is pushed up and since its overflow is hidden, it disappears outside the viewport. Set overflow to scroll to see what happens exactly

Comment: Do you have this problem anywhere other than on jsfiddle? It doesn't seem to happen on jsbin for instance. So I think it might just be a bug on jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi I think the problem is in the destination page, if you try the next url with # the problem is not: <iframe src="http://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#scxml" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Reproducing script

Found a minimal way to reproduce the bug: http://jsfiddle.net/4oytgwon/1/embedded/result/ (you can see the bug happening after clicking on "load iframe").

It also happens outside of jsfiddle using the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body, html {
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #header {
                height: 50px;
                background: blue;
            }
            #content {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
            #overflow {
                position: absolute;
                height: 50px;
                bottom: -50px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function loadIframe() {
                var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
                ifr.src = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#See_also';
                var content = document.getElementById('content');
                while (content.firstChild) {
                    content.removeChild(content.firstChild);
                }
                content.appendChild(ifr);
            }
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('btn').onclick = loadIframe;
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=header>
            <button id=btn>load iframe</button>
        </div>
        <div id=content>
        </div>
        <div id=overflow>
            overflow
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm still not convinced this gets to the bottom of it. Replace the wikipedia page with a page that contains no javascript at all - eg http://w3.org/TR/scxml/#scxml, and the effect is not seen. What I want to know is what it is about the wikipedia page that makes this occur.

Comment: my guess is its related to scrollIntoView.  a fix shipped in chrome around the same time as this issue. i know this is old, but i'm seeing this issue now with scrollIntoView causing the parent to scroll in addition to iframe.  there is a bug open here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=819314

Answer (score 16):

As other answers have already mentioned, the issue here is specific to JSFiddle. I can show you that with ease by simply including the same code within a StackOverflow snippet on this question:

```css
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://news02ycombinator02com2.mentionusercontent.net/item?id=8357207#up_8360397" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

---

## Simpler HTML document

This issue happens with every fragment URL passed into an `iframe` on JSFiddle. Because of this, we can replicate this issue simply be creating a separate JSFiddle demo and linking to that in our `iframe`.

I've created this new JSFiddle demo here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/JamesD/k5vk2u9h/1/show/light/#test.

As you can see, the fragment here is `#test`. This issue is now replicable in a new JSFiddle demo using the following markup:

```
<iframe src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/JamesD/k5vk2u9h/1/show/light/#test"></iframe>
```

The `height` and `width` attributes are irrelevant as the issue still appears without them.

### [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/xzonssqz/).

---

## A workaround

The other answer here suggests that the fix is to modify JSFiddle's own HTML in order to re-render the page correctly. This isn't a great solution as in a real world situation (i.e. when linking someone to a JSFiddle demo), they may not have the expertise to achieve this.

We can get around this by using JavaScript. As the new HTML document I've created is on the same domain (http://jshell.net) we can execute JavaScript within the `iframe` itself. Manually setting the `location.hash` property will also trigger this issue, so what we can do instead is scroll the `iframe` directly to the element we wish to focus on.

Firstly, remove the fragment from the URL in the `src` attribute of our `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/JamesD/k5vk2u9h/1/show/light/"></iframe>
```

As mentioned above, the fragment I've used is an element whose `id` is "test". This means the easiest way to get our element is to select it by its `id` attribute:

```
var frame = frames[0],
    elem = frame.document.querySelector('#test'),
```

Here, `frame` is a reference to our `iframe` within our own document, and `elem` is our `#test` element. We can get our matched element's position by using `getBoundingClientRect()`:

```
    position = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
```

This will give us a ClientRect object like the following:

[image: ClientRect]

With this we now know that our `#test` element is positioned 3034px from the top of our `iframe`. Using this, we can now scroll the page ourselves to this position using `window.scrollTo()` (where the `window` of our `iframe` in this case is held in our `frame` variable):

```
frame.scrollTo(0, position.top);
```

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/et1oj1ph/).

*Note that this solution will only work if the `iframe` points to a URL hosted on the same domain or if CORS has been enabled on the page the `iframe` is embedding.*

---

### The best option

After doing all this though, the best bet is to simply notify the developers of JSFiddle that this is a bug. I've raised this as an issue on their GitHub repository here: https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/547.

Comment: This is not a jsFiddle bug. The iframe causes its parent document to scroll up.

Comment: @arnaud576875 I haven't been able to replicate this outside of JSFiddle. As others here have mentioned, this error isn't present in CodePen and JSBin.

Comment: This is actually the whole point of the question: how to reproduce this :)

Comment: @arnaud576875 that's the point - you can't because it's a JSFiddle bug. To reproduce it you'd have to copy the code JSFiddle to `iframe` elements included within its results pane. I don't think I deserve a downvote for this, because I have displayed a simpler JSFiddle method of reproducing the bug, and I've provided a workaround - both were things mentioned in the question. There was no mention of these bugs having to be reproduced outside of JSFiddle in the [original edit you made](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/668a4bbb-1f87-4df3-8998-26b504066382/view-source).

Comment: Oops, that should read "copy the code JSFiddle [applies] to `iframe` elements...".

Comment: Successfully reproduced the bug outside of JSFiddle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26454250/4159587

Answer (score 8):

### Revised Answer

There are **two bugs** being displayed here.

1. JSFiddle looses part of it's header when loading an iFrame with a fragment. This is discussed in other answers and in my "Old Answer" section. And a github issue has been raised.
2. iFrames on chrome handles fragments badly. They cause scrolling on the parent. (This may be desired behavior to be fair).

### Chrome iFrame problem

When you run this, your window will scroll so that the fragment in the window is at the top of your page:

```html
<iframe src="https://news02ycombinator02com2.mentionusercontent.net/item?id=8357207#up_8360397" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

As you can imagine, this causes issues in certain fixed height websites like jsfiddle. It is also unique to Chrome (I've only tested on FF, not IE), Firefox doesn't scroll the parent window. There is a discussion about it not being in FF [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638598).

### Chrome iFrame parent scrolling fix

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmz5cu1y/31/)

Add an onload event to the iframe that calls the following function. And don't use the fragment in the original:

```html
<script>
    function loadorder() {
    document.getElementById("iframename").src= "https://news02ycombinator02com2.mentionusercontent.net/item?id=8357207#up_8360397";
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
</script>
<iframe width="830" src="https://news02ycombinator02com2.mentionusercontent.net/item?id=8357207" height="500" id="iframename"  onLoad="loadorder();"></iframe>
```

As you can see in both the fiddle and the above snippet, the parent window no longer scrolls and the behavior is now the same for both FF and Chrome.

**[Source for fix.](http://www.mytechmusings.com/2006/12/iframe-scroll-to-anchor-problem.html)**

### Old Answer (alternate fix for jsfiddle)

> Okay, so I did some testing:
>
> - Issue only on Chrome
> - Issue occurs with any fragment linked page: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wmz5cu1y/14/)
> - Issue is specific to jsfiddle. [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaDwr) and [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cahudutacuno/1/edit) work fine.
>
> So as a temporary workaround either use one of those or inject this
>   into jsfiddle's html:
>
> ```
> margin-top: 30px; into the header bar like:
>
> <div id="header" style="margin-top: 30px;">
> ```
>
> Bit of a pain though since it needs to be done everytime you load
>   jsfiddle (but not every time you run the fiddle).
>
> To get the problem fixed, it should be reported on the jsfiddle github
>   page: https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues
>
> **Edit**
>
> And here is a way to automate it on chrome: Download the [stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en)
>   extension, and add this style to jsfiddle.com (or the specific
>   fiddle):
>
> ```
> #header {
>     margin-top: 30px;
> }
> ```
>
> It works pretty well.

Comment: I would have to agree with this answer, iFrames for some reason have always given me issues in jsFiddle, and occasionally in CodePen as well.

Comment: @Adjit I believe it's because they do some security related processing to the iframe content that adds some limits and causes various bugs. That's what I understood from reading some issues on github anyway.

Comment: right, is the OP's issue jsFiddle in Chrome specific or just Chrome specific?

Comment: @Adjit He only mentioned Chrome but it seems to be specific to jsfiddle+chrome.

Comment: @Adjit Thanks, your comment made me rethink some things and I realized there was a more fundamental problem.

Comment: This is not a jsFiddle bug. The iframe causes its parent document to scroll up.

Comment: I don't think the first claim (Issue occurs with any fragment linked page: example) is true. See eg http://jsfiddle.net/wmz5cu1y/23/

Comment: @ChrisLear it happens on that link for me.

Comment: @arnaud576875 You're right, I've updated my answer to be clearer. There are two bugs not one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not to include # in a iframe url, if you try with the next url in your example you will see there is no scroll:
http://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#scxml

So, I reviewed the page that you are showing to see if there is something weird:
https://news02ycombinator02com2.mentionusercontent.net/item?id=8357207#up_8360397

If you check the JS it has something like the next:

```
      var e = window,
    g = document,
    h = "documentElement",
    k = "CriticalImages",
    l = "scrollTop",
    n = "prototype",
    p = "body",
    q = "getAttribute",
```

There is a function called "scrollTop" which I think is a good candidate to investigate.

If you check the code a little bit more you will see that in some point the JS is getting the offsetTop and the offsetParent:

```
 u = function(a, b) {
        var c = b[q]("pagespeed_lazy_position");
        if (c) return parseInt(c, 0);
        var c = b.offsetTop,
            d = b.offsetParent;
        d && (c += u(a, d));
        c = Math.max(c, 0);
        b.setAttribute("pagespeed_lazy_position", c);
        return c
    },
```

Conclusion: the issue is with the page that your are trying to show in your iframe, not with fiddle nor Chrome or # in the urls.

I hope this help.

---

### EDIT

After reviewing the wiki example I see that is some js in the fiddle (so the first answer is right).

To avoid this with js you just include this:

```
$( window.parent ).scroll(function(event) {
   // debugger;
  console.log('SCROLL',event);
  var scrollTop=$(this).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop>0){
      console.log('fix scroll');
      $(this).scrollTop(0);
  }

});
```

Example:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/xbnt3Lu6/21/

I will try to review which js is causing the problem.

Comment: It would be nice if the people who downvote leaves a comment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well its not only chrome , all browsers will have the same problem, seems like the site has heavy js scripting , no idea how but it does affect on the site you put iframe on, the easiest way solving it is removing the **#up_8360397** from the link.
Second way would be disabling javascript inside the iframe. but than you won't be able to auto scroll it down to the post you wanted, u'll have to set scroll positions manually.

Comment: So far, I have not managed to reproduce it outside of Chrome this is why I'm still looking for a workaround or wait for a fix in Chrome.

Comment: I have also found that a) it only occurs in Chrome, and b) only occurs where there is javascript running in the iframe.