# Page jumps to top when iframe is clicked

Tags: iframe

My page jumps to the top when I embed this gdrive iframe, once you click on the iframe:

```
<iframe height="400px" frameborder="0" width="600px" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u9NFjTPBd-9mucQUPvkqLP84iV6uaEcJNF5vQdHmYh8/edit?usp=sharing&rm=embedded"></iframe>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0qpe53os/

Question: Why does it do so and how can I prevent it from doing so?

I tried to `preventDefault` without any luck. Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Mybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017978/iframe-causes-parent-elements-to-scroll-up-on-google-chrome-when-url-contains-fr

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017978/iframe-causes-parent-elements-to-scroll-up-on-google-chrome-when-url-contains-fr

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is useful. By the way you could use the onload attribute to scroll the page down:
**onload="scroll(0,screen.height);"**

```
<iframe height="400px" frameborder="0" width="600px" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u9NFjTPBd-9mucQUPvkqLP84iV6uaEcJNF5vQdHmYh8/edit?usp=sharing&rm=embedded"  onload="scroll(0,screen.height);"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my investigation, its not caused by the iframe itself. Its cause by the javascript executed by the embedded google docs. When the editing area of the google docs receives the focus this happens. If you access the menu area nothing happens unless it results something being added to the editing area. I tried restricting the iframe with sandbox attribute and this behavior no more happens, but of course you cannot use the google docs.

Sorry no solutions to suggest.

Answer (score -2):

You could use javascript to check if the iframe is the active element and jump back to it if it is active.

`if(document.activeElement.tagName == 'IFRAME') {
    document.activeElement.scrollIntoView()
  }`

See this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8p6n8und/) for a working example.